# Opening a Modal in React with an ID passed to the component

Tags: reactjs

I have an application which prompts a user to add an entry via a modal. However, I can't figure out how to call the modal from the function and neither can I figure out how to pass the id to the modal.

So far I've been able to get the two parts written up and compiled but not working together

#### 'Add Entry' button

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css'
import VideoModal from '../components/VideoModal'

function NewEntry ({event}){
      return (    
          <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <VideoModal entry={event}
      );
  }

export default NewEntry;
```

Note that this doesn't call the modal component. I've attempted variations of `onClick={this.closeModal}` for the `<I>` tag to no avail, but this obviously won't work. And I've included the modal as a component.

I know, I *know* this isn't the right way of doing this, I just haven't yet found examples I can wrap my head around.

#### The Modal

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import '../../App.css'


class VideoModal extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };

  openModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoModal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `VideoModal` tag is not closed, pay attention to it.

Then you can move the open/close logic outside the modal, inside `NewEntry`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../App.css'
import VideoModal from '../components/VideoModal'

class NewEntry extends Component {
  state = {
    isModalOpen: false
  };

  openModal = () => this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
  closeModal = () => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });

  render() {
      return (    
          <span onClick={() => this.openModal()}><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <VideoModal closeModal={() => this.closeModal()} isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
      );
  }
}

export default NewEntry;
```

And use `VideoModal` as a pure component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import '../../App.css'


function VideoModal (props) {
    const { isOpen, closeModal } = props;
    return (
      <>
        <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={closeModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={closeModal}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
}

export default VideoModal;
```

Comment: I see broadly how this works and I'm implementing it. How do I trigger the modal? In an ideal world I wanted to do it on pressing `<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Comment: I updated the answer with `onClick` event on <span> tag

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work. The span renders without the `onclick` and I end up with the unclickable plus icon.

Comment: I got it. The `isOpen` on the `<VideoModal>` tag was misspelt. It should have been `isModalOpen`. this fixes it. Thanks!